# Unit Testing Typescript for Compiler Errors

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

Is there a library or some form of built-in support in Typescript for writing unit tests to assert that some code does *not* compile? It would be be especially nice if the precise error message / code could also be tested for.

For example, I would like to assert that the following code:

```
expect(tsErrorCode`const x="a";const y:number=x`).toBe("TS2322")
```

or

```
expect(tsCompiles`const x="a";const y:number=x`).toBeFalsy()
```

Comment: Worth looking at https://github.com/Microsoft/dtslint to see if it meets your needs. It includes functionality for writing implementation files with expected errors

Answer (score 2):

As of Typescript 3.9, there is compiler directive comment called @ts-expect-error that does what you want. You use it on a line preceding an expected compiler error. Typescript will give you an error if the line *doesn't* error.

So with your example, you'd have code like this:

```
const x="a";

// @ts-expect-error
const y:number=x;

const y:string=x;
```

More documentation can be found here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments